# Setting keystore & truststore in Android using System.setProperty

Tags: java, android, keystore, truststore

In Android, is it possible to set up a keystore and truststore for an SSL socket using

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore","theKeystoreFilename");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","theTruststoreFilename");
```

Or should I make a `Keystore` object instead?  If so, where should I put the keystore file?  In assets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, android doesn't use those properties. Also you can't really set system-wide properties from an app, so this doesn't make much sense. Create `KeyStore` objects and load/add certificates as needed. If the set of trust anchors is static, you can store the raw file in assets. Storing keys is not really a good idea, since anyone can extract the.